# Switching between two LAN ports?

Tags: dd-wrt

I'm seeing some strange behavior with my DD-WRT setup (FW v V24sp2), where traffic from my wireless network portion of the LAN to the wired LAN works, but I cannot SWITCH from two machines connected to the wired LAN, even though I have connectivity and WAN access from everywhere.  Has anyone seen something like this before?  For example,

192.168.10.146 is connected to LAN port 1, and 192.168.10.220 is connected to LAN port 2, and they cannot see each other, but wireless clients can see both of them, and they both have WAN connectivity.

My knowledge of networks is pretty spotty, but I don't think there's anything unusual in my configuration, and I would expect that LAN trafic would route by default.

**Reference data**

```
root@router:~# nvram show | grep vlan.*ports 
size: 20411 bytes (45125 left) 
vlan0ports=1 2 3 4 5* 
vlan1ports=0 5 
root@router:~# nvram show | grep vlan.*hwname 
size: 20411 bytes (45125 left) 
vlan1hwname=et0 
vlan0hwname=et0 
root@router:~# nvram show | grep port.*vlans 
size: 20411 bytes (45125 left) 
port5vlans=0 1 16 
port3vlans=0 
port1vlans=0 
port4vlans=0 
port2vlans=0 
port0vlans=1 
root@router:~#
```

Comment: Recheck your terminology: are you saying that **switching** between two LAN ports of your WRT does not work? i.e. confirm that you actually have IP addresses in the same network (like `192.168.1.x` & `192.168.1.y` if your WRT is `192.168.1.1`)

Answer (score 0):

Check VLAN configurations. Are the LAN ports on different VLANs?
What is the next-hop seen to the Internet from machines on both LAN ports? (is it the same IP?)

Update: I think you have inadvertently reached a [VLAN Detached Networks](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Detached_Networks_%28Separate_Networks_With_Internet%29) configuration.

Update2: a quick starter [reference](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Default_Configuration_Overview) (or [this one](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=431294#431294)).

Comment: root@router:~# nvram show | grep vlan.*ports
size: 20411 bytes (45125 left)
vlan0ports=1 2 3 4 5*
vlan1ports=0 5
root@router:~# nvram show | grep vlan.*hwname
size: 20411 bytes (45125 left)
vlan1hwname=et0
vlan0hwname=et0
root@router:~# nvram show | grep port.*vlans
size: 20411 bytes (45125 left)
port5vlans=0 1 16
port3vlans=0
port1vlans=0
port4vlans=0
port2vlans=0
port0vlans=1
root@router:~#

Comment: This from the docs looks normal, right?

Comment: Hmm, I am not used to WRT configurations. And your wrapped comment does not help my yet un-caffeinated mind. From what I gather, your configuration seems to be defaults from A VLAN standpoint. Why don't you format your outputs and place them in your question area? That way you will get faster help.

Comment: Yeah. I tried, but no matter what I can't figure out how to format this... isn't that silly?  I'm not usually this clueless.

Comment: did an initial patch to your question...

Comment: Nik. Thanks for all your help.  I will have to look at this and see if I can do any other tests to rule out other hardware in the mix.